# Default image (logo) for customizer

Tags: php, images, theme-customizer, logo

I want to let users upload a logo. I've tried a few things. Currently there is a broken image until a logo is uploaded. I need to set the default as logo.png in my theme folder. Here's how it stands now,

functions.php:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'img-upload' );
$wp_customize->add_control(
new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
$wp_customize,
'img-upload',
array(
    'label' => 'Logo Upload',
    'section' => 'logo',
    'settings' => 'img-upload',
    'default-image'  => get_template_directory_uri() . '/logo.png'
        )
    )
);
```

index.php:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('img-upload');?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" class="logo" />
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Edited the question for clarity. I want to set a default image for the image upload feature.